# AIR/Flash Player connect to another machine without cirrus/stratus

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, networking, air

Is it possible to connect to a Air app running on another machine via socket(assuming we know ip) or some other mechanism(which doesnt use Cirrus/stratus)? If it is can someone please help me on how?

---

Let me rephrase question, I dont want to connect to a server over socket. I would like to know if it is possible to connect from one AIR app on machine A to connect to another AIR app on machine B via sockets without  cirrus. I'm not asking for someone else to do my work, I couldnt find any documentation or possibility of the above thing. My conclusion now is that it is not possible, but I would just like it to be verified by other people(experts).

Comment: This looks more like one of those can you do my work for me questions. And yes it is possible with sockets

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, as3 supports sockets.  http://www.ultrashock.com/forum/viewthread/81676/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it. One AIR app can act as a server by creating a ServerSocket object while  the other app connects to this with the Socket class. The other way is to use the DatagramSocket class.

In both cases, the trick is that because of network access translation, the IP address to use is not always easily discoverable unless at least one of the computers has a static IP. If both computers are on the same network subnet you can look up the IP address needed to reach one computer from the other manually. Otherwise, the IP one computer must use to reach the other won't be the same IP that the computer sees for itself. This matchmaking is the service that stratus/cirrus provides.

See http://www.brynosaurus.com/pub/net/p2pnat/ for a description of the problem.